# Why can't outer join simplification happen for embedding outer join?

Tags: mysql, optimization, join

The MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html) suggests the following:

> Sometimes the optimizer succeeds in replacing an embedded outer join operation, but cannot convert the embedding outer join. The following query:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
>               (T2 LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.B=T2.B)
>               ON T2.A=T1.A
>   WHERE T3.C > 0
> ```
>
> Is converted to:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
>               (T2 INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.B=T2.B)
>               ON T2.A=T1.A
>   WHERE T3.C > 0
> ```
>
> That can be rewritten only to the form still containing the embedding outer join operation:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT JOIN
>               (T2,T3)
>               ON (T2.A=T1.A AND T3.B=T2.B)
>   WHERE T3.C > 0
> ```

Why can not we convert the 'embedding' left outer join in this case into inner as well? Since `T3.C > 0` is null-rejecting, `T3.B=T2.B` becomes null-rejecting. Consequently shouldn't `T2.A=T1.A` also be null-rejecting?

Overall, can't the embedded query can be treated like below?

```sql
SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.A=T1.A
                 LEFT JOIN T3 ON T3.B=T2.B
  WHERE T3.C > 0
```

Is there a reason behind this? It is just another form of writing the query right? Why is it being treated like subquery?

Comment: I suspect the other `LEFT JOIN` could be turned into `INNER JOIN`, too

Comment: Please file a bug report with bugs.mysql.com.